# How should I send a Polygon with a hole for the Winding number Point in Polygon test?

Tags: c++, polygon, point-in-polygon

I want to check if a point is in the Polygon (which can have a hole/holes within it).  Right now a polygon with a hole is represented as multiple polygons when the hole and the outside polygon doesn't have a common vertex. Under these circumstances how should the points of the polygon be send to the [function](http://geomalgorithms.com/a03-_inclusion.html) (found at the bottom) ?.
Would sending an array of points be valid?

Answer (score 1):

The point is inside the polygon if and only if it is inside the outer perimeter of the polygon and outside the hole.

If you are not told which polygon is which, it doesn't matter; the point is inside the complex polygon iff it is inside exactly one of the two.